# Как подключить шрифт в фрагменте?

Tags: android, typeface

Мне нужно подключить шрифт в фрагменте. Когда делал в активити, то работало.

В фрагменте такая строчка:

```
Typeface myfonts = Utils.getTypeFace(this, "fonts/a_BentTitulDcFr.ttf");
```

Далее для нужного текста в этом фрагменте я подключаю `myfonts` с нужным шрифтом.

```
mSelectedItemView2 = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.selected_item2);
mSelectedItemView2.setTypeface(myfonts);
```

Код класс `Utils.java`

```
public class Utils {

private static final Hashtable<String, Typeface> cache = new Hashtable<String, Typeface>();

public static Typeface getTypeFace(Context context, String assetPath) {
    synchronized (cache) {
        if (!cache.containsKey(assetPath)) {
            try {
                Typeface typeFace = Typeface.createFromAsset(context.getAssets(), assetPath);
                cache.put(assetPath, typeFace);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.e("TypeFaces", "Typeface not loaded.");
                return null;
            }
        }
        return cache.get(assetPath);
    }
```

Собственно он ругается при компиляции:

```
    Error:(40, 33) error: method getTypeFace in class Utils cannot be applied to given types;
required: Context,String
found: Fragment2,String
reason: actual argument Fragment2 cannot be converted to Context by method invocation conversion
```

пытался поменять `Context` на `Fragment2` в классе `Utils`, но не заработало: не нашел метод `getAssets()`.

Comment: Здесь ясно написано, что требуется контекст, а класс Fragment не является его наследником (в отличии от активити)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Попробуйте так:

```
Typeface myfonts = Utils.getTypeFace(getActivity(), "fonts/a_BentTitulDcFr.ttf");
```

Comment: все заработало, спасибо

Comment: @Алексей, Отлично! Если ответ помог вам справиться с проблемой - следует отметить его как верный

Answer (score 2):

Приведу пример того, как я решил подобную проблему:

```
import android.graphics.Typeface;

public class FontsHelper {

    private static FontsHelper instance;
    private static Typeface roboto_regular;
    private static Typeface roboto_medium;


    private FontsHelper() {
    }

    public synchronized static FontsHelper instance() {
        if (instance == null) {
            instance = new FontsHelper();
        }
        return instance;
    }

    public void setFontRobotoRegular(Typeface typeface) {
        FontsHelper.roboto_regular = typeface;
    }

    public void setFontRobotoMedium(Typeface typeface) {
        FontsHelper.roboto_medium = typeface;
    }

    public static Typeface getFontRobotoRegular() {
        return roboto_regular;
    }

    public static Typeface getFontRobotoMedium() {
        return roboto_medium;
    }

}
```

В Main Activity:

```
private void setRobotoFont() {    
robotoRegularFont = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "fonts/Roboto-Regular.ttf");
 robotoMediumFont = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "fonts/Roboto-Medium.ttf");
                setFontsHelper();
            }



private void setFontsHelper() {
    FontsHelper.instance().setFontRobotoRegular(robotoRegularFont);
    FontsHelper.instance().setFontRobotoMedium(robotoMediumFont);
}
```

Используя класс-хелпер вы можете устанавливать нужные вам шрифты в приложении где они потребуются безо всяких проблем.